# UNION in Dynamic SQL - TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The purpose of the below script is to gather the sum total of database sizes and the number of databases from each server and then sum it all up for a grand total.

```
DECLARE @LinkedServer   VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL1           NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL2           NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TotalDB        NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @TotalSize      NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @LineSpace      VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Union1         VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @Union2         VARCHAR(200)

SELECT @LinkedServer = MIN(name)
    FROM ServerwithLinkedServers.master.sys.servers
    WHERE name IN ('ServerName1',
                    'ServerName2',
                    'ServerName3')

WHILE @LinkedServer IS NOT NULL 

    BEGIN
        SET @TotalDB = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Total Retailer Databases] FROM '+ @LinkedServer +'.master.sys.databases';
        SET @Union1 = @TotalDB + ' UNION ' + @TotalDB;
        SET @TotalSize = 'SELECT CAST(SUM(size) * 8.00 / 1024.00 / 1024.00 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS [Total Size GB] FROM '+ @LinkedServer +'.master.sys.master_files';
        SET @Union2 = @TotalSize + ' UNION ' + @TotalSize;

        EXEC (@Union1);
        EXEC (@Union2);

        SELECT @LinkedServer = MIN(name) 
            FROM ServerwithLinkedServers.master.sys.servers 
            WHERE name IN ('ServerName1',
                           'ServerName2',
                           'ServerName3')
                AND name > @LinkedServer
    END

    print @union1
    print @union2
```

However, when I execute the code I am getting an error stating:

```
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'T'.
Incorrect syntax near 'T'.
```

What am I missing? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print your statement instead of execution - and examine it. Error message clearly says - your have missed quotation mark somewhere.

Comment: Why are you looping here? And what is the point of pulling data from the remote system? You have hard coded the values anyway so there really is no point in reading the list of servers (unless one of them has been dropped from the remote server). And then you are getting the count of databases from each server twice. This whole thing could be rewritten without looping quite easily but I don't understand what it is trying to do.

Comment: I need to have the hard coded ServerNames because some of the linked servers don't work anymore (some servers have been decommissioned). The script is suppose to retrieve the number of database per server and at the same time get the sizes. And the UNION it all together for a grand sum. How would I re-write this script without using the loop?

Comment: You would rewrite it by UNIONing the SELECTs from ServerName1, ServerName2 and ServerName3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can leverage dynamic sql for this kind of thing without using a loop. I also rewrote your queries as a single query for each database. This will return the number of databases on each server and the total amount of space used by the files. I would suggest tweaking this a little bit to exclude certain databases like master, tempdb, model etc...

This will still return the entire list but no need for looping. Once you are comfortable with the dynamic sql it generates you can comment out that line and uncomment the exec line.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'select count(distinct d.database_id) as TotalRetailerDatabases
    , CAST(SUM(size) * 8.00 / 1024.00 / 1024.00 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) TotalSizeGB
from ' + name + '.sys.master_files mf
join ' + name + '.master.sys.databases d on d.database_id = mf.database_id UNION ALL '
FROM ServerwithLinkedServers.master.sys.servers 
WHERE name IN 
(
    'ServerName1'
    , 'ServerName2'
    , 'ServerName3'
)

set @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) --remove the last UNION ALL

select @SQL
--exec sp_executesql @SQL1
```

Comment: What do you mean by remove the last UNION ALL?

Comment: Take a look at the string created without removing the last 10 characters, it will have a trailing UNION ALL. :) Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't see a T by itself in your query, I have to assume you have a ServerName with T followed by a space.

Try using `QUOTENAME(@LinkedServer)` everywhere in your query where you have `@LinkedServer`.